# knockoutjs: Why is there an empty object sent along?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, knockout.js

I am trying to write rails3 crud views using knockoutjs. Somehow I am getting a behavior quite different from the tutorials and would be thankful, if you could give me some hints...

My code is more a less a replication of the [loading and saving data tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving). I load the data from the server, do nothing at all, save and the controller gets and additional, 'empty' object, which somehow is persisted. However changes to existing data never is, neither deletes.

May I show the code:

```
%ul#folders{'data-bind' => 'foreach: folders, visible: folders().length > 0'}
  %li
    %span{'data-bind' => 'text: id'}
    %span{'data-bind' => 'text: name'}
    %span{'data-bind' => 'text: description, visible: description'}
    %a{'data-bind' => 'click: $parent.removeFolder'}Excluir

%button{'data-bind' => 'click: save'}Salvar

%form{'data-bind' => 'submit: addFolder'}
  Add folder:
  %input{'data-bind' => 'value: newFolderName', 'placeholder'=>"Nome"}
  %button{type: "submit"}Adicionar

=content_for :script do
  :javascript

    function Folder(data) {
      data = data || {id: 0, name: "", description: ""};
      this.id = data.id;
      this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
      this.description = ko.observable(data.description);
    }

    function FolderListViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.folders = ko.observableArray([]);
      self.newFolderName = ko.observable();

      $.getJSON("/folders", function(allData) {
        var mappedFolders = $.map(allData, function(item) {
          return new Folder(item);
        });
        self.folders(mappedFolders);
      });

      self.addFolder = function() {
        self.folders.push(new Folder({name: self.newFolderName()}));
        self.newFolderName("");
      };

      self.removeFolder = function(folder) {
        self.folders.remove(folder);
      };

      self.save = function() {
        console.log(self.folders());
        $.ajax("/folders", {
          data: ko.toJSON({folders: self.folders}),
          type: "post",
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function(result) {
            return console.log(result);
          }
        });
      };
    }

    $(function(){
      ko.applyBindings(new FolderListViewModel());
    });
```

Saving (independent if there are changes or not) always yield a similar request:

```
Started POST "/folders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-04 22:57:40 +0100
  Processing by FoldersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"folders"=>[{"id"=>2, "name"=>"dim sum", "description"=>"ist warm!"}, {"id"=>3, "name"=>"Sushi", "description"=>"roh und kalt"}, {"id"=>1, "name"=>"Spagetti", "description"=>"Carbonara"}, {"id"=>10, "name"=>"Wiener", "description"=>"vom Kalb"}, {"id"=>11, "name"=>"Feijão", "description"=>""}], 
"folder"=>{}} <== LOOK HERE
  Folder Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "folders".* FROM "folders" ORDER BY "folders"."row_order"
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Folder Load (0.2ms)  SELECT id, row_order FROM "folders" ORDER BY "folders"."row_order" DESC LIMIT 1
  Folder Load (0.2ms)  SELECT id, row_order FROM "folders" WHERE "folders"."row_order" = 8388592 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "folders" ("created_at", "description", "name", "row_order", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 21:57:40 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["name", nil], ["row_order", 8388592], ["updated_at", Wed, 04 Jan 2012 21:57:40 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/folders/21
Completed 302 Found in 54ms
```

Also deleted objects are only removed from the array and I wonder how rails should figure out, that it should strip them from the object store... everything is just a post... this looks all wrong to me.
What is my mistake?

Two bonus questions:
I dislike spamming my global js namespace with these constructor functions, but if I try to hide them inside an anonymous function, it seems ko does not find them anymore. Can this be remedied?

How can I tell rails globally, to stop redirecting me to html actions on json requests (how stupid is that anyways) and just send me an ok message or the errors?

Answer (score 0):

For the global variables you can remedy that by creating a namespace for them and/or wrapping your code for this page in a function/object that represents your viewmodel. For example:

var my = my || {}; // your namespace. likely define this in one place for your entire app.

Then you can define your view model as you normally would, or even wrap it inside of a self invoking function (as shown below). I highly recommend the viewmodel approach, so all of your behavior for your page is hanging off one object.

```
(function (my, ko) {
    "use strict";
    my.viewmodel = {
        firstName: ko.observable(),
        lastName: ko.observable()
    };
}(my, ko));
```